# Visual Studio Unit Tests Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I am using Visual Studio for a C# application.

In my PC i had installed Gallio, which is a set of test tools (including a test runner). My Unit tests are normal unit tests using the NUnit framework. At my PC, Visual Studio can identify and run the tests.

But when i change PCs, or when i un-installed Gallio from mine, Visual Studio cannot longer find the unit tests giving a message as below:

**"No Tests were run because no tests were loaded or the selected tests are disabled"**

I know that the fact that my projects cannot be loaded, is because of Gallio. When i was adding a Test class in my project the **Test Type** was set to **Gallio**. I tried almost everything to make Visual Studio being able to find my test classes again but without any luck.

Does anyone have the same problem? Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Are your classes decorated with `[TestClass]` and methods with `[TestMethod]`? Are they not appearing at all or are grayed out (`[Ignore]`)?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz thanks for your answer. My classes are decorated with [TestFixture] and my methods with [Test] as i am using NUnit framework. The test classes are not appearing at all either in the <b>Test List Editor</b> or the <b>Test View</b>. Even using NUnit, shouldn't they appear there?

Comment: NUnit isn't intrinsically available in VS 2010. Only MSTest style tests can be used - unless you use plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have a test runner for NUnit. It can only execute MSUnit tests by default without using an add-on like Resharper. Visual Studio 2012 does now include a runner for NUnit among other testing frameworks.

You have the following options:

1. Port your tests to use MSUnit; or
2. Upgrade to Visual Studio 2012; or
3. Install an add-on like Resharper that has a NUnit runner built in.

Comment: Jack thank you for your answer. Indeed you answer makes sense. That's why when i had Gallio i used to be able to run the tests from inside Visual Studio and when i uninstalled it i couldn't anymore. It seemed to me strange and i didn't know how VS works. I was struggling with that half day now. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that MSTest and NUnit use different attributes to flag tests:

```
// MSTest
[TestClass]
public class MsTests
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void MyMethod()
}

// NUnit
[TestFixture]
public class NUnitTests
{
   [Test]
   public void MyMethod()
}
```

You have to do a swap, or use both if you want it to be available to both frameworks. However MSTest does not like methods with parameters, whereas NUnit does.